# dojo : how to copy a dojo component to local directory and make it work

Tags: javascript, dojo

We have extended/customized dojo for our projects inside the company. our toolkit is called xwt.

I am considering making a copy of the sample file that is part of the toolkit into a local directory and start using it. So, I copied the SampleExtendedIFWS.js file into the local directory and changed the namespace it uses from dojo.provide("xwt.widget.tests.table.store.SampleExtendedIFWS") to dojo.provide("SampleExtendedIFWS").

From my application page(jsp), I started using dojo.require("SampleExtendedIFWS") -- however, now it is expecting the file from /app/resources/dojoroot/SampleExtendedIFWS.js and not the local directory.

How can I make dojo/xwt take the local directory version of SampleExtendedIFWS.js instead of expecting from /app/resources/dojoroot/SampleExtendedIFWS.js ?

Answer (score 0):

Anjan

you need to specify your own namespace else it will look into dojoroot.
so at the same level as where you have dojo and xwt, you can create your own directory, lets say anjanb and put your SampleExtendedIFWS.js and change the dojo.provide to call it anjans.SampleExtendedIFWS

Now, in your sample HTML, you need to specify the module path in djConfig. For example:

```
djConfig = {
        isDebug: false,
        debugAtAllCosts: false,
        parseOnLoad: true,
        baseUrl: "<path to where your dojo.js resides>",
        modulePaths: {
            'xwt': '../xwt',
            'anjans' : '../anjans'
        }
    };
```

Note that the module path is always relative to where dojo.js resides

do a dojo.require of your object:

```
dojo.require ("anjans.SampleExtendedIFWS");
```

this should get you going

btw, If you wish to extend the functionality, dojo provides more elegant mechanisms to extend the object instead of copying and changing by using dojo.extend, for example.